# Add Custom Web Service (from a custom web server) to a Visual Studio Project (Outlook Addin)

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, outlook

I'm working on an Outlook Addin (Ribbon with button) in VS 2012 Ultimate.

On the ribbon button click I want to speak with a webservice and bring up a message showing whatever parsed info from the webservice.

The custom webservice is not .net, or anything microsoft. It's a simple webservice that can return almost any kind of information, but lets say XML.

How do I add a custom xml web service (eg. localhost/mywebservice.xml) to a Visual Studio project, to be used in a button click, where the webserver running on localhost is not IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of VS client libraries that answer this question.

The one I went with was RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/).